# XQuery grouping

Tags: xml, xquery

What XQuery will result in the following output ? Given the following XML

XML -

```
<build id="b0">
   <dept>IE</dept>
   <dept>EE</dept>
   <name>alpha</name>
   <type>lib</type>
   <year>1000</year>
   </build>
<build id="b1">
   <dept>IE</dept>
   <name>beta</name>
   <type>teach</type>
   <type>lib</type>
   <year>1000</year>
</build>
```

Expected Output

```
<group dept="EE" count="1"/>
<group dept="IE" count="2"/>
```

group department wise and print its count, where year is 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following (corrected) `input.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <build id="b0">
        <dept>IE</dept>
        <dept>EE</dept>
        <name>alpha</name>
        <type>lib</type>
        <year>1000</year>
    </build>
    <build id="b1">
        <dept>IE</dept>
        <name>beta</name>
        <type>teach</type>
        <type>lib</type>
        <year>1000</year>
    </build>
</root>
```

you can use this XQuery expression/file

```
let $file := doc("a.xml")
for $cur in distinct-values($file/root/build[year=1000]/dept)
order by $cur
return <group dept="{$cur}" count="{count($file/root/build/dept[. = $cur])}" />
```

to get the following, desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<group dept="EE" count="1"/>
<group dept="IE" count="2"/>
```